# What would be the best way to add groves to this control knob?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

I am learning blender for school and I need some help, I want to add groves to this control knob in the picture, but I'm not sure what would be the best way to go about it.

Should I try editing the mesh? Or should I try to construct a cutter piece?

Thanks in advance if you can help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way to do it is to use the *Simple Deform* modifier / *Bend* mode:

- Create your segment:

[image]

- Array it (enable the *Merge* option of the *Array* modifier):

[image]

- Give it the *Simple Deform* modifier / *Bend* mode:

[image]

- You can continue to work on the segment as much as you want, when you're glad with the result, apply the *Array* and *Simple Deform* modifiers (keep the *Subdivision Surface* if possible), merge the vertices:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll go and try this method/modifier now

Comment: If you meet any problem please let me know  ;)

Comment: Hi I've managed to get to the point where I am adding the simple deform modifier, but it doesn't go the way I want it to, only if I set the origin to my reference photo does it bend the way I want it to, how do you rectify that?

Comment: apply the rotation in Object mode (Ctrl A) and choose Z as axis in the modifier

Comment: Ah okay, didn't know I was supposed to apply the rotation, thank you very much, it's done now